# Spark driver always fail to bind to submit host in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I'm trying to deploy Spark streaming job using standalone cluster. All the jars are installed locally on each node and I run spark-submit inside one of the nodes. The driver is then started in one of the workers randomly but always try to bind to the node where I submitted the job. And if it happens to be on a different node, the driver always fails. I tried to set spark.driver.host to different values but didn't help.

Anyone with the same problem? Or is there any better ways to submit spark jobs, ideally in Standalone cluster.

> spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077

export SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=local_host_name
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/var/log/spark
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/var/run/spark/work
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/var/run/spark/tmp
export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=master_host_name
```

> spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.master                       spark://master_host_name:6066
spark.io.compression.codec         lz4
```

I run it with spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --supervise

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you share what is there in logs and your configuration?

Comment: have you forgot to put configuration for slaves? The nodes mentioned in salves file under conf directory are the actual workers where jobs are submitted. On spark UI you can check the number of workers available.

Comment: yes, all workers are able to join and I am able to submit job. It works perfectly fine when the worker in which the driver runs on is the same as the machine I use to submit the job

Comment: This should not happen, what error you are getting in logs? without that I can't help you.